# How to get contents of a file on my computer from my website?

Tags: php, python, json, curl, xmlhttprequest

I want to get the contents of a file on my computer from my website , But not uploading it to that website and then get the contents because the file contents changes dynamically , I tried to turn the folder that contains that file to a URL so the URl whould be something like that : http://127.0.0.1:port or http://myIpAddress:port ,

and tried to use both **file_get_contents()** and **cURL** but I got errors and they are not working ,
 I allowed **xmlHTTPrequest** to the directory but still can't use it .

Some of the errors:

when using 127.0.0.1:port :
1- file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Connection refused
2- curl faild to connect to 127.0.0.1

when using my ip then the port:
1- file_get_contents no route to host
2- curl bool(false)

So is there is another way to get contents from a file from my website ?

Comment: How often does that file change. Can't you have a script running on your pc that uploads a new copy of the file in regular intervals? btw. you need to forward a port in your router if you want to access your pc over the internet.

Comment: There are more than 1 file , first : what kind of scripts are you talking about ? is it a php script or what?

Comment: second : for the router should i enter only the port or the hole url ? and would i need the tool that makes the folder as a url or just this router issue?

Comment: You could use a python script running on your PC which then uploads the files in question to your website every few minutes or so. There are many [websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=router+port+forwarding&oq=router+port+forwarding) that explain how to forward a port. You need to enter only the port and the ip address of your PC. btw. the "tool that makes the folder as a url" is called a webserver. For example [this software](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)

Comment: I'm using this extension , So how to forward a port ?

Answer (score 2):

In your server CD to directory you want to serve, then

```
python3 -m http.server
```

By default it runs http server on 8000 port but you can specify custom port in argument